# How to write byte array to StorageFile in WindowsPhone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, arrays, storagefile

I searched and found this but it's not available for Windows Phone 8 and only works for Windows Store apps:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileio.writebytesasync

How do I do this in WP8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use binary writer:

```
byte[] buffer;   

using (IsolatedStorageFile ISF = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{

  using (IsolatedStorageFileStream FS = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, ISF))
  {
    using (BinaryWriter BW = new BinaryWriter(FS))
    {
      BW.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Lenght);
    }
  }
}
```

Or make it simpler as @KooKiz said:

```
using (IsolatedStorageFileStream FS = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, ISF))
 {
     FS.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Lenght);    
 }
```

Comment: Why use a BinaryWriter? `fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);`

Comment: ISF if defined on the second line.